# How to split a text file at lines which begin with a number

Tags: awk, sed, split

I have a file ('tosplit') that looks like this:

20210101 blah blah
blah 20210101
blah 20210101
blah 20210101
20210315 blah blah
blah 20210315
blah 20210315
blah 20210315

I would like to split this file into two files that look like this (i.e., each file contains the line starting with the date and all of the lines that follow and start with 'blah'):
(file 1)
20210101 blah blah
blah 20210101
blah 20210101
blah 20210101
(file 2)
20210315 blah blah
blah 20210315
blah 20210315
blah 20210315

Using csplit (>csplit -z tosplit /2021/ '{*}'), doesn't work, as the delimiter occurs multiple times in the block I am trying to preserve as a single file. Is there a way to split based on the first character of the line being a number and not a letter? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You can split on zero-width matches of `(?<=\n)(?=\d)`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2oc4YF/1)

Comment: `(?<=\n)` is a *positive lookbehind* that asserts that the match is preceded by a newline character. `(?=\d)` is a *positive lookahead* that asserts that the match is followed by a digit.

Comment: how many new files do you expect to create? what is the format of the names for the new files? will you always be splitting on what appears to be an 8-digit date (`YYYYMMDD`) at the beginning of the line (ie, could there be more/less than 8 digits to consider)? you've tagged the question with `bash` and `sed` ... have you tried any `awk` or `sed` commands and if so ... could you update the question with said commands?

Comment: what to do with lines that don't start with a `blah`? or do you want to save *ALL* lines that come after the 8-digit date?

Comment: Why not `csplit -z file '/^[0-9]\{8\} /' '{*}' `?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this `awk` if the condition is always `2021`.
It generates files (and overwrites existing ones without asking) with names `fileX` with X being the number of splits.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{x=1} NR>1 && /^2021/{ close("file"x); x++ } 
    { print > ("file"x) }' tosplit

$ for i in file[12];do echo $i; cat $i ;done      
file1
20210101 blah blah
blah 20210101
blah 20210101
blah 20210101
file2
20210315 blah blah
blah 20210315
blah 20210315
blah 20210315
```

A more generalized version

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{x=1} NR>1 && /^[[:digit:]]/{ close("file"x); x++ } 
    { print > ("file"x) }'
```

Comment: `print > "file"x` is undefined behavior per POSIX (any expression on the right side of input or output redirection must be wrapped in parens) and it'll result in a "too many open files" error from most awks once you get past a threshold that could be as low as about 15 output files. It'll do what you want in GNU awk but YMMV with any other awk.

Comment: @EdMorton Very good point. Always close open pipes/sockets/connections. A clear oversight. Adding a fix.

Comment: And then just change `print > "file"x` to `print > ("file"x)` for it to be portable to all awks.You don't need to flush btw, close() will do that.

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
cat tosplit
20210101 blah blah
blah 20210101
blah 20210101
blah 20210101
20210315 blah blah
blah 20210315
blah 20210315
blah 20210315
2021 blah
blah
```

You can use `csplit` by adding an anchor `^` to specify only to use `2021` at the start of the line:

```
csplit -z tosplit /^2021/ '{*}'
61
61
15
```

Which creates the files:

```
xx00:
20210101 blah blah
blah 20210101
blah 20210101
blah 20210101
xx01:
20210315 blah blah
blah 20210315
blah 20210315
blah 20210315
xx02:
2021 blah
blah
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##fYvLCsIwFETXvV8xBCVQkD7EjYJfIkKaNiRQktJkURS/PbbR4kbKheHM4U4jvI6xk9qB12VdlfOh6YVOQYlWv9kSHKvT3/HsN9sCvw3HNTg/9CaASH7g8MDqivvyXoA/8xcnUm6EsjAW05Rf0DpQNozGBgW29@ebZWA7ZRllUoQvts52WYxv)